# menu Items not listed under visual studio 2017

Tags: testing

When I log into Visual Studio 2017. I am trying to associate a test case. The option is greyed out.  Is there something I have to do before to make it enabled.? See screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is an interesting workaround but the option wasn't available because VS 2017 is defaulting to MSTestV2 and this option was only available in MSTestV1.  As of Visual Studio 2017 15.7.1, this option is available without running in compatibility mode and will work for all unit test frameworks such as MSTestV2, xUnit, and NUnit test cases.  Here is some more information on this.  http://www.deliveron.com/blog/test-case-association-xunit-nunit-and-mstestv2-tests-available-visual-studio-2017-1571/

Answer (score 0):

For those who need help in future.

Solution =
  Click on Tools ==>> Options ==>> Work Items ==>
 ==>> Select the option "Compatibility Mode"

This should fix the Issue.

Thanks